# NFS volume mount times out on Kubernetes with incorrect IP?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

> 97    Mounting command: systemd-run 98    Mounting arguments:
>   --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/06b9ae42-8e99-11e9-b888-a44c24184b19/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-data
>   --scope -- mount -t nfs 10.100.155.82:/exports/www /var/lib/kubelet/pods/06b9ae42-8e99-11e9-b888-a44c24184b19/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-data
>   99    Output: Running scope as unit:
>   run-r26f9da6c287846589bec8d059c33441d.scope 100   mount.nfs: Connection
>   timed out
>
> 101       FailedMount Warning 2019-06-14T11:48:46Z
>   102   typo3-app-67b58d7657-cvqdg  Pod Unable to mount volumes for pod
>   "typo3-app-67b58d7657-cvqdg_default(1fb4c719-8e9a-11e9-b888-a44c24184b19)":
>   timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod
>   "default"/"typo3-app-67b58d7657-cvqdg". list of unmounted
>   volumes=[nfs-data nfs-data-src]. list of unattached volumes=[nfs-data
>   nfs-data-src
>   default-token-lmtl4]  FailedMount Warning 2019-06-14T11:49:04Z

Weirdly I have no idea where it's getting `10.100.155.82` from? This was the  the previous IP of the `ClusterIP` (relating to the nfs service)...

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: typo3-app
  labels:
    app: typo3
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: typo3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: typo3
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: us.gcr.io/objit-chris/chrisjitit-typo3:v11
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/www/html-chrisjitit
            name: nfs-data
          - mountPath: /var/www/typo3_src-6.2.6
            name: nfs-data-src
      volumes:
        - name: nfs-data
          nfs: 
            # https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3417
            # server is not resolved using kube dns (so can't resolve to a service name - hence we need the IP)
            #server: 10.11.250.37
            server: 10.97.78.206 
            path: /exports/www
        - name: nfs-data-src
          nfs: 
            # https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3417
            # server is not resolved using kube dns (so can't resolve to a service name - hence we need the IP)
            #server: 10.11.250.37
            server: 10.97.78.206 
            path: /exports/www/typo3_src
```

What may be the cause of this timeout / wrong IP being used?

---

I tried deleting the deployment, changing the name that still didn't seem to work, but few minutes later it worked... Really strange behavior?

---

Ran into this issue again...:

```
 kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM              STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
nfs-data                                   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Available                                              67m
pvc-f1353542-a8b1-11e9-bdf7-38ffa66115bc   10Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound       default/nfs-data   standard                67m
```

---

```
kubectl get pvc
NAME       STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
nfs-data   Bound    pvc-f1353542-a8b1-11e9-bdf7-38ffa66115bc   10Gi       RWO            standard       67m
```

Comment: Could you provide output of `kubectl get pvc` and `kubectl get pv` ?

Answer (score 0):

It keeps picking up an old NFS IP. It's a bug...:

```
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/9470ac17-a8b9-11e9-bdf7-38ffa66115bc/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-data-src --scope -- mount -t nfs 10.11.250.37:/exports/www/typo3_src /var/lib/kubelet/pods/9470ac17-a8b9-11e9-bdf7-38ffa66115bc/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-data-src
Output: Running scope as unit: run-ref2095cb52c94d0c87de5458c3b16733.scope
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I never got to the bottom of this no. :( It's probably a bug.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems the quickest fix is to find where this stale IP is and update it. But I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Alternatively you could mount it directly by some other means. Maybe even a side container responsible for mounting the NFS mount, and then sharing a volume with the container.